# How do I make a build system for Sublime 3 to compile the current cs file? (C#)

Tags: c#, sublimetext3

For example, if my current file in sublime is foo.cs, I want it to run "csc /out:foo.exe foo.cs". I don't want to run a full msbuild.

Answer (score 6):

In Sublime, choose menu Tools > Build System > New Build System
Paste in the following text. Save it as "C#.sublime-build".

```
{
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "del", "${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}", "2>NUL", "&&", "csc", "/nologo", "/out:${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?)[(]([0-9]*),([0-9]*)[)]",
    "variants": [
        { "name": "Run", "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "start", "cmd", "/c", "${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}"] }
    ],
}
```

Or this alternative line builds and runs it all when you put ctrl-b:

```
"cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "del ${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/} 2>NUL && csc /nologo /out:${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/} $file && start cmd /c ${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}"],
```

Comment: Ctrl-b builds, Ctrl-shift-b runs, F4 jumps to the next error

Comment: Thank you. I edited the second line a bit and now works perfectly: {
 "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "del ${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/} 2>NUL && C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\csc.exe /nologo /out:${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/} $file && ${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}"],
}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Build System with the following configurations.

```
{
"cmd":["csc","$file"],
"selector":"source.cs",
"variants" :
[
    {
        "cmd" : "$file_base_name.exe",
        "name"  : "run",
        "shell" : true,
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below C#.sublime-build compiles and runs any c# program in a new pop-up console. But it only applies for windows users. Other os users may change the "cmd" key's value a little bit in the following C#.sublime-build to make their custom C#.sublime-build system. Hope, it will be helpful:

```
{
   "cmd": ["csc", "$file_name", "&&", "start","cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name.exe"],
   "file_regex": "^(...?):([0-9]):?([0-9]*)",
   "working_dir": "$file_path",
   "selector": "source.cs",
   "shell": true,
   "quiet": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this and your OK

```
{
"cmd": ["csc", "/out:$file_base_name.exe", "$file_name"],
"selector": "source.cs",
"shell": true,
"working_dir": "${file_path}",

"variants": [
    {
        "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "csc", "/out:$file_base_name.exe", "$file_name", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name.exe"],
        "name": "Build and Run",
        "shell": true,
        "working_dir": "${file_path}"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).